# Deedle F# - Find the max rows within an index group

Tags: dataframe, f#, deedle

I am trying to get the difference between the first and last values within groups in a deedle data frame.  I am stuck at trying to get the max and min values for each point.  I have a dataframe sorted by "TimeStamp", grouped by "Test" and with a column called "Value" of type float.  For example with the following data:

```
Test1,2018/01/01 => 3
Test1,2018/01/02 => 5
Test1,2018/01/03 => 15
Test1,2018/01/04 => 25
Test1,2018/01/05 => 35
Test2,2018/01/01 => 5
Test2,2018/01/02 => 15
Test2,2018/01/03 => 15
Test2,2018/01/04 => 25
Test2,2018/01/05 => 30
```

I expect a result of

```
Test1 => 32    (35-3)
Test2 => 25    (30-5)
```

I assume I can use something like

```
input |> applyLevel fst Stats.maxBy |> Frame.ofRows
input |> applyLevel fst Stats.minBy |> Frame.ofRows
```

but I can not seem to get it to work no matter the combinations.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test this, I saved your sample data in a CSV file in the following format:

```
Category, Timestamp, Value
Test1, 2018/01/01, 3
Test1, 2018/01/02, 5
Test1, 2018/01/03, 15
Test1, 2018/01/04, 25
Test1, 2018/01/05, 35
Test2, 2018/01/01, 5
Test2, 2018/01/02, 15
Test2, 2018/01/03, 15
Test2, 2018/01/04, 25
Test2, 2018/01/05, 30
```

Now, I think the issue with using `Stats.max` and `Stats.min` is that they return option which is `None` when the series is empty - this sadly makes it impossible to pass them directly to `applyLevel` (I admit this is a bit inconvenient design)

However, you can pass a custom function to `applyLevel`, which also allows you to do both `min` and `max` at the same time:

```
Frame.ReadCsv("sample.csv")
|> Frame.groupRowsByString "Category"
|> Frame.applyLevel fst (fun s -> 
    match Stats.min s, Stats.max s with
    | Some lo, Some hi -> hi - lo
    | _ -> nan)
```

This reads the CSV file (which will introduce a new ordinal key), then it groups the data by category (which gets you a data frame with row key `string * int`) and then we aggregate all rows with the same `string` key using `applyLevel fst`. The custom function gets minimum and maximum of the value series and subtracts it (the case with `nan` would only happen if you had some missing values in `s`).

Comment: Thank you, that helped.  This helped me solve my problem.